# D3 + React Tooltip Not Showing

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, visualization, heatmap

I built a basic heatmap in html using d3, and the tooltips show properly. I've got the same code working in React, and the heatmap is working, and the mouseover, mousemove, and mouseleave functions are working (and the data is printing into the console accurately), but no matter what i try, I can't get the tooltip to actually show up. Any help would be appreciated

Below is my code-

```
import rd3 from 'react-d3-library';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import React from 'react';
import data2 from '../data/hmap_current_year.csv';

const node = document.createElement('div');

 // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
 const margin = { top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 29, left: 60 },
 width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 630 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3
 .select(node)
 .append("svg")
 //add mobile-friendly
 .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width + margin.left + margin.right} ${height + margin.top + margin.bottom}`)
//  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
//  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

d3.csv(data2).then(function (data) {
 const var0 = data.map(function (d0) {
     return {
         month: d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d0.time).getMonth(),
         day: d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d0.time).getDate(),
         value: d0.tmed
     }
 })

 const myGroups = Array.from({ length: 31 }, (_, i) => i + 1)
 const myMonths = [
    "Jan", 
    "Feb", 
    "Mar", 
    "Apr", 
    "May", 
    "Jun", 
    "Jul", 
    "Aug", 
    "Sep", 
    "Oct", 
    "Nov", 
    "Dec"
    ]

 // Build X scales and axis:
 const x = d3.scaleBand()
     .range([0, width])
     .domain(myGroups)
     .padding(0.01);
     svg.append("g")
     .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
     .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
     .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove());

     svg.append("g")
     .call(d3.axisTop(x))
     .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove());

 // Build X scales and axis:
 const y = d3.scaleBand()
     .range([0, height])
     .domain(myMonths)
     .padding(0.01);
     svg.append("g")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
     .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove());
     svg.append("g")
     .call(d3.axisRight(y))
     .attr("transform", `translate(${width}, 0)`)
     .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove());

 // Build color scale
 const myColor = d3.scaleQuantile()
     .domain([0, 5, 20, 40, 60, 80, 95, 100])
     .range([
        "#08306B", 
        "#2171B5", 
        "#6BAED6", 
        "#FFFFFF", 
        "#FCBBA1", 
        "#FA6A4A", 
        "#CB181D"
    ]);

 // create a tooltip
 const tooltip = d3.select(node)
     .append("div")
     .style("opacity", 0)
     .attr("class", "tooltip")
     .style("background-color", "white")
     .style("border", "solid")
     .style("border-width", "2px")
     .style("border-radius", "5px")
     .style("padding", "5px")
     .style("margin-bottom", '51px')

 // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
 const mouseover = function (event, d) {
         tooltip
         .style("opacity", 1)
         d3.select(this)
         .style("stroke", "black")
         .style("opacity", 1)
 }
 const mousemove = function (event, d) {
         tooltip
         .html("The exact value of<br>this cell is: " + d.value)
         //accessing values correctly
         console.log(d.value, 'HELLO')
         .style("left", (event.x) / 2 + "px")
         .style("top", (event.y) / 2 + "px")
 };
 const mouseleave = function (event, d) {
         tooltip
         .style("opacity", 0)
         d3.select(this)
         .style("stroke", "none")
         .style("opacity", 1)
 }

 svg.selectAll()
     .data(var0)
     .join("rect")
     .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.day) })
     .attr("y", function (d) { return y(myMonths[d.month]) })
     .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
     .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
     .style("fill", function (d) { return myColor(d.value) })
     .style("stroke", "none")
     .on("mouseover", mouseover)
     .on("mousemove", mousemove)
     .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
});

const RD3Component = rd3.Component;
class HeatmapInteractive extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {d3: ''}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({d3: node});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <RD3Component data={this.state.d3}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default HeatmapInteractive;
```

Answer (score 0):

here you have done perfectly for defining the tooltip initially

```
const tooltip = d3.select(node)
     .append("div")
     .style("opacity", 0)
     .attr("class", "tooltip")
     .style("background-color", "white")
     .style("border", "solid")
     .style("border-width", "2px")
     .style("border-radius", "5px")
     .style("padding", "5px")
     .style("margin-bottom", '51px')
```

but while hovering you dont have to select any node by using d3.select(this) in **`mouseover`** and **`mouseleave`** state

**you've written this**

```
const mouseover = function (event, d) {
         tooltip
         .style("opacity", 1)
         d3.select(this)
         .style("stroke", "black")
         .style("opacity", 1)
 }
```

you can simply remove the d3.select(node) from chaining

**Insted of doing like that you can simple change only opacity in mouseover**

```
 const mouseover = function(event, d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 1)
  }
```

**if it's mouseleave just reverse**

```
const mouseleave = function(event, d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
  }
```

**if it's a mousemove then you have to add `html` and `postion properties` for dynamic float of tooltip according to the mouse values like**

**Note** one more thing dont use console in middle of chaining that may break the chaining, if you have tested with it then have to remove otherwise it won't work

```
const mousemove = function (event, d) {
         tooltip
         .html("The exact value of<br>this cell is: " + d.value)
         .style("opacity", 1)
         .style("left", (event.x) + 20 + "px")
         .style("top", (event.y) + 20 + "px")
 };
```

i hope this answer will get clarifies you

Comment: I tried everything you suggested and it still didn't work; the tooltip can be visible, but not the text at all, which is so strange.

Comment: may be then problem is in this line `const tooltip = d3.select(node)`  does this element is available for selectiong, you can add one div element to the documet and select that just like this https://codepen.io/codingdarci/pen/ZERpNOG understand this may be you can get where you have missed the point